# I tried to run a flutter app taken from Github on AndroidStudio, but appears this error

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying this application https://github.com/pelusodan/FridgePal
But why appears this error? What should I do?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
  ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
  : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Sviluppo\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Sviluppo\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: That code is very old, don't expect to run right away. Latest versions of Flutter uses nullability, some methods are deprecated, etc

Comment: thank you very much for this explanation. I'm new on flutter and I didn't know that